# *Why* were the Chernobyl control rods tipped with graphite?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, history, nuclear-engineering

I understand the graphite tips of the boron control rods displaced water (a moderator) which lead to an increased reaction rate, rise in temperature and steam pressure etc.

Question: why were the control rods tipped with graphite at all? What purpose did that serve?

Comment: There was a lot of graphite in the Chernobyl reactor. Why is putting graphite on the tip (that likely mates into a hole in graphite) a problem?

Comment: Well it turned out to be the final straw that catalysed the disaster, so it was a huge problem at the end. But I mean the question is not "why not" but "why?" why not have the control rods pure boron?

Comment: Oh, the disaster was well on its way, whether graphite tipped or not.

Comment: I agree with this (I used the word catalyst). Nonetheless, the graphite tips of the rods was a conscious and explicit design decision. A choice I wonder what the justification for this was

Comment: Re, "the final straw," When the camel's back is broken, do you pick up the final straw, and lay all of the blame on it? or do you blame the guy who was heaping the stuff onto the poor beast's back? The cause of the disaster wasn't Russian-designed graphite tips. It was poorly-trained control-room operators, who did not understand how the reactor was behaving, who had no clue what it was capable of, and who disabled crucial safety systems and went completely off the script. That could happen anywhere, in any reactor whose owners are more concerned with profits than with safety.

Comment: Yes I know. My question is not about the cause of the disaster. I am not really interested in chernobyl, at least for this question. My question is simple- why design boron control rods, purposefully, to have graphite tips. There must be a motivation to do that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Tipped" is a somewhat simplistic term that has been repeated so often it has become fact.  In fact the use of graphite for part of the control rods is more involved that "tip" might suggest.

The report :

- INSAG-7  The  Chernobyl  Accident : Updating  of  INSAG-1  A  REPORT  BY  THE INTERNATIONAL  NUCLEAR  SAFETY  ADVISORY  GROUP

  - [Link to download page](https://www.iaea.org/publications/3786/the-chernobyl-accident-updating-of-insag-1)
  - ISBN  92-0-104692-8
  - Safety report No. 75

goes into some detail on the design of the rods.

> 2.2.   DESIGN  OF  CONTROL  AND  SAFETY  RODS
>
> The control  rods  and the  safety  rods  of an RBMK reactor  are  inserted  into the reactor  core  from  above,  except  for  24  shortened  rods  which are  inserted  upwards and  which are  used  for  flattening the  power  distribution.  A  graphite  rod  termed  a displacer  is attached  to each  end  of  the length of  absorber  of  each  rod,  except  for twelve  rods that are  used  in automatic control.
>
> The lower displacer  prevents  coolant water  from  entering the  space vacated  as the rod  is withdrawn, thus augmenting the reactivity worth of the rod. The graphite displacer  of each  rod of all RBMK reactors was,  at  the time  of the accident,  connected  to  its rod  via a  'telescope',  with a water filled  space  of  1.25  m  separating  the  displacer  and  the  absorbing  rod  (see  Fig.  1).
>
> The dimensions of rod and displacer  were such that when the rod was fully  extracted the displacer  sat centrally  within the  fuelled region  of the core with  1.25  m of water at either end.  On receipt  of a  scram  signal causing a  fully  withdrawn rod  to fall, the displacement  of  water  from  the  lower part  of  the  channel  as  the  rod  moved  down-wards from  its upper limit stop position  caused a local insertion of positive  reactivity in the lower part of the core. The magnitude of this 'positive scram'  effect  depended on  the  spatial  distribution  of  the  power  density  and  the  operating  regime  of  the reactor.

So the use of graphite had more than one purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The graphite displacer improved the efficiency of the cycle by improving the geometry and 'coupling' between the upper and lower active sections of the core when the control rod was fully withdrawn. At the 'full out' position the displacer improves the flux pattern and reduces the amount of heat absorbed by the Control Rod Channel Cooling System. Allowing this space to be full of water would be a 'small' but continuous thermal loss for each withdrawn rod. The displacers would save significant operating cost over the life of the unit.

Answer (score 1):

The Soviet designers of the RBMK reactors, such as those at Chernobyl, used control rods tipped with graphite for several reasons, although it ultimately contributed to the positive void coefficient issue, a significant factor in the Chernobyl disaster.

1. Reactivity Control: Graphite at the tip of the control rods helped maintain reactor stability during low-power operation by providing additional neutrons. This allowed for a more flexible power output.
2. Cost and Availability: Graphite was a readily available and cost-effective material in the Soviet Union. Using graphite as a moderator and as a part of the control rod design was economically advantageous.
3. Operational Flexibility: The RBMK reactors were designed to produce both electricity and weapons-grade plutonium, which required flexibility in their operation. The use of graphite-tipped control rods allowed for this flexibility.

However, this design choice had unintended consequences. When the control rods with graphite tips were inserted into the reactor, they displaced water coolant and increased the reactor's reactivity, causing a temporary power surge. This, combined with other factors like operator errors and a flawed safety culture, led to the catastrophic explosion and meltdown at the Chernobyl Nuclear Power Plant in 1986.

In hindsight, the positive void coefficient issue was a critical design flaw, and subsequent reactor designs incorporated safety improvements to avoid such a disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I’m wrong -  it’s my understanding that the Soviet Union did not have sufficient amount of U – 235,
So they used the graphite tipped (a lot of graphite by the way- “tipped is an understatement) in order to supplement the fueling reactor , much like using grapefruit juice with Viagra (lol). The issue was that they powered it down too quickly in an effort to make their deadline (it was an experiment was prescribed by the state - aka men who had no idea about nuclear physics and how a reactor worked - much less one that was built in 1954 and was outdated). It’s my understanding that they powered it down too quickly - I think to either 2.5 or 7%. This is where I need help. Does powering it down mean less steam is produced, so in other words, less water is supplied? If that is the case, water served a dual purpose. It’s both a cooling agent for the super hot reaction but also what generated the power  -  think of a nuclear reactor as a fancy, more efficient steam engine that creates no byproduct waste like coal or natural gas. So when there was no water to vaporize, the reactor overheated. The operators tried to power it back up, meaning put more water in, but it didn’t work because it was too hot. So when that didn’t work, they inserted more rods which, because they were tips of graphite, the water was insufficient to cool and/or steam because it was so hot, so basically like let out energy and so it exploded. Am I right? I think of it as putting a hot pan on a stove for like 30 minutes and trying to add water. Like it will not vaporize, it’ll just burn the pan. I am not a scientist by any means, and there isn’t enough technical literature out there that explains it. I mean if you Google it - it still says it was caused by “operator error,” which is so wrong. The operators had an instruction/ procedure sheet that they had to go off of based on the state’s mandates (aka not scientists) and they were several Soviet and Europeans scientists who published (well the Soviet scientists were largely disregarded, but the Europeans and Americans reformatted their reactors) against the use of graphite rods as fueling rod- what do they use now btw? I don’t know if anyone will read this but please let me know. I’m a history major and always had a great interest in the political issues the explosion raised and its great affect on the ultimate dissolution of the USSR, but I’ve always been curious as to why it exploded, technically.